# Canvas size changed by itself

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I'm a total noob when it comes to programming. So I got this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkjw5raq/1/) which is just perfectly what I need. But the problem is when I try to embed it to my wordpress, it doesn't work just like fiddle. The canvas that is supposed to render the image with text doesn't work.

Instead, it only shows a small image like it was failed to load. With a quick inspect element I got this line:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="16" height="16" data-block-type="core"> </canvas>
```

Why the size changed and what is data block type? How to get the code right?

Comment: The canvas seems to be 16x16. It will be helpful if you provide with more detail. How the canvas is created etc.,

Comment: I use the exact same code with the fiddle. Embedded the script in the html body and I insert script jquery js to head.